# ASP MVC - how to edit model enum values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider the following enum in my Model:

```
 public Icings Icings { get; set; }
 public enum Icings
{
    [Display(Name = "Almond Butter Cream")] AlmondButterCream = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Butter Cream")] ButterCream,
    [Display(Name = "Butter Cream Icing")] ButterCreamIcing,
    [Display(Name = "Chocolate Butter Cream")] ChocolatebutterCream,
    [Display(Name = "Fondant Accents")] FondantAccents,
    [Display(Name = "Key Lime Butter Cream")] KeyLimeButterCream,
    [Display(Name = "Lemon Butter Cream")] LemonButterCream,
    [Display(Name = "Marshallmallow Fondant")] MarshallmallowFondant,
    [Display(Name = "Orange Butter Cream")] OrangeButterCream,
    [Display(Name = "Strawberry Cream Cheese")] StrawberryCreamCheese,
    [Display(Name = "White Chocolate Butter Cream")] WhiteChocolateButterCream,






}
```

I currently have a drop down where the user can input their filling.
I want to add the ability for an admin to add/delete an icing to this model for users to select, how would this be possible?

Comment: Then do not use an `enum` (Enums are meant to be constants defined at compile time). Store the values in a database table

Comment: Not a good idea to use `enum` in CRUD operations (see [System.Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx) definition). To enable CRUD, replace the enum with data model class which representing `Icings` table contents in DB and use LINQ methods to retrieve data.

Comment: why are u not adding this List to database